# A question about a limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{1/x}$ where $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\cfrac{x^{a_k}}{a_k!}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234237/lim-limits-x-to-inftyfx1-x-where-fx-sum-limits-k-0-infty-cfra)

Suppose $\{a_k\}$ be an strictly increasing sequence with positive integers.

Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cfrac{x^{a_k}}{a_k!}$. does $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)^\frac{1}{x}$ exist? and how to compute.

Comment: Since $f(x) \leq e^x$ for $x \geq 0$, $f(x)^{1/x}$ is bounded above by $e$. Thus both limsup and liminf exist. But I think that some deliberate choice of $(a_k)$ can make $f(x)^{1/x}$ oscillate as $x \to \infty$.